# Not able to display fragment when menu item is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm having a difficulty to show a fragment in a container when a menu item is clicked.Below is my code.

I tried to do `ft.show();` inside onMenuItemClick of Login Menu Item but its not working and I don't know what am I doing wrong as I'm neither getting any errors nor the app is crashing. Fragments which are attached to the Tabs are working and displaying just fine. It's just that when I try to load a fragment in an container when menu item is clicked at that time nothing happens.Please point me in a right direction and lemme know what am I doing wrong.

```
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

public SherlockFragment fragment;
FragmentTransaction ft;
public static Context appContext;
ActionBar actionbar;
String mCurFilter;
LoginScreenFragment loginFragment;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    appContext = getApplicationContext();
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab HomeTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Home");
    ActionBar.Tab CartTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Cart");
    ActionBar.Tab myTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("MyFragment");
    ActionBar.Tab moreTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("More...");

    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    CartFragment cartFragment = new CartFragment();
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    MoreFragment moreFragment = new MoreFragment();
    loginFragment = new LoginScreenFragment();

    HomeTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(homeFragment));
    CartTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(cartFragment));
    myTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(myFragment));
    moreTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(moreFragment));

    actionbar.addTab(HomeTab);
    actionbar.addTab(CartTab);
    actionbar.addTab(myTab);
    actionbar.addTab(moreTab);

    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment);
    ft.show(homeFragment);
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, cartFragment);
    ft.hide(cartFragment);
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);
    ft.hide(myFragment);
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, moreFragment);
    ft.hide(moreFragment);
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, loginFragment);
    ft.hide(loginFragment);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getSupportActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    System.out.println("onSaveInstanceState");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
    item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    View searchView = SearchViewCompat.newSearchView(this);
    if (searchView != null) {
        SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener(searchView,
                new OnQueryTextListenerCompat() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
                return true;
            }
        });
        item.setActionView(searchView);
    }
    MenuItem loginItem = menu.add("Login");
    loginItem.setTitle("Login");
    loginItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    loginItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
//I wanted to show "loginFragment" when the Login button is clicked.But unfortunately its not showing up.Also the application is not giving any errors or crashing
            ft.show(loginFragment);
            return false;
        }

    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.menuitem_home) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (itemId == R.id.menuitem_shop) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext, "Shop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (itemId == R.id.menuitem_cart) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext, "Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (itemId == R.id.menuitem_my) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext, "My", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (itemId == R.id.menuitem_more) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext, "More...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public SherlockFragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(SherlockFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        System.out.println("TabReselected " + tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        System.out.println("TabSelected " + tab.getPosition());
        ft.show(this.fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        System.out.println("TabUnselected " + tab.getPosition());
        ft.hide(this.fragment);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you check if fragments are really added..?

Comment: @Swati thanks for the reply.Yes the fragments are added all the fragments that are attached to the Tabs are showing up.Its just the loginFragment which is not attached to any tabs is not showing up when i do ft.show(loginFragment) on it inside onMenuItemClick.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the fragments to one container and hiding & showing them you can try replacing fragments when you click on your menu buttons.

for ex- when you click on login button

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, loginFragment).commit();
```

give it a try hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried this and its giving me error saying "commit already called".As i already called commit() in onCreate.

Comment: just remove adding over there and replace here. That error is caused may be because its already been added in your layout in case you have not removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should begin and commit the transaction again. Try:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.show(loginFragment);
    ft.commit();
    return false;
}
```